# using xmlReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlreader

i am trying to read an xml string and then modify it by inserting another xml string, i dont know how to do this, i was struggling since i am a beginner in this area. i search the net and i was really confussing between xmlWriter and xmlReader cuz i dont want to use xmlDocument 
i found this from microsoft 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

so my code is like this

```
 String Mainxmltext = "<ClosedKPICalls>" +
    "<ServiceInfo>  <ServiceNo>HR011</ServiceNo> <ServiceName>Petty cash</ServiceName>    "+
    "<RecCount>0</RecCount>  <RegdKPI>2</RegdKPI>  </ServiceInfo> </ClosedKPICalls>";

    String xmlinnerText = "<TaskDetails> <name>Jhone</name> <Description>just for testing</Description> </TaskDetails>";

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(Mainxmltext)))
    {
        XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
        ws.Indent = true;
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, ws))
        {

            // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {

                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);                           
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        writer.WriteString(reader.Value);

                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                    case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                        writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                        writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        writer.WriteFullEndElement();                           
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    MessageBox.Show(output.ToString());

}
```

so i am successfully read the first string now how can i insert the second test before the closing tag of the main xml i mean before  and my xml should look like this

```
<ClosedKPICalls>
<ServiceInfo>  
<ServiceNo>HR011</ServiceNo> 
<ServiceName>Petty cash</ServiceName>  
<RecCount>0</RecCount>  
<RegdKPI>2</RegdKPI>  
</ServiceInfo>
<TaskDetails> 
<name>Jhone</name> 
<Description>just for testing</Description> 
</TaskDetails>
</ClosedKPICalls>
```

please help
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linq2Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx) is easier to use.

```
String Mainxmltext = "<ClosedKPICalls>" +
        "<ServiceInfo>  <ServiceNo>HR011</ServiceNo> <ServiceName>Petty cash</ServiceName>    " +
        "<RecCount>0</RecCount>  <RegdKPI>2</RegdKPI>  </ServiceInfo> </ClosedKPICalls>";

String xmlinnerText = "<TaskDetails> <name>Jhone</name> <Description>just for testing</Description> </TaskDetails>";

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(Mainxmltext);
xDoc.Root.Add(XElement.Parse(xmlinnerText));
var newxml = xDoc.ToString();
```

That is all to get your desired xml

Comment: Is XElement is not sufficient? Do we really need XDocument? because there is no root, declaration in the xml.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and its working perfectly, but what if i want to add xmlinnerText in multiple place in MainxmlText cuz in this case it will add it only before the last tag. also XDocument will effect the memory?

Answer (score 0):

I all you are trying to achieve is insert a piece of xml to an xml string you could use the `XElement` class to achieve that.

For ex.

```
var xmlString = "<person></person>";

var xEl = XElement.Parse(xmlString);

xEl.Add(XElement.Parse("<name>vijay</name>"));

Console.Writeline(XEl);
```

O/P

```
<person><name>vijay</name></person>
```

Google for `XElement`.